# Get pass or fail output from Django unit tests

Tags: python, django, bash, testing

For my Django project I am trying to get 0 or 1 output from `python manage.py test` for whether or not all the tests have passed.

I'm wanting to run the tests in a bash script and then have the script know whether or not all the tests have passed, and if so continue to do some other actions.

This is the closest I've been able to get, but the output is not right

```
output=$(python manage.py test)
output=$(python manage.py test 0 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the exit status (`$?`) of the `manage.py test` command, [which exits with a status of `1` whenever at least one test fails (or for any error), otherwise exits with `0` when all tests pass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/test.py#L55).

[Stdlib `unittest` also has the same behavior](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/main.py#L273).

So in essence, you premise is wrong and actually your checking is not correct  -- you're saving the STDOUT from `python manage.py test` in variable `output` in the first example, your second example would raise an error unless you have a package named `0` that has module(s) `test*.py`; if you have such a package then the second command will save both STDOUT and STDERR from the `manage.py test 0` command as variable `output`.

You can either check for the exit status of the *last* command using `$?`:

```
python manage.py test
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    # Success: do stuff
else
    # Failure: do stuff
fi
```

But there's a better way, shells can check the exit status implicitly in `if`:

```
if python manage.py test; then
    # Success: do stuff
else
    # Failure: do stuff
fi
```

---

If you don't care for STDOUT/STDERR, you can redirect those streams to `/dev/null`, POSIX-ly:

```
if python manage.py test >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Success: do stuff
else
    # Failure: do stuff
fi
```

Bash-ism (works in other advanced shells):

```
if python manage.py test &>/dev/null; then
    # Success: do stuff
else
    # Failure: do stuff
fi
```

Comment: This is a detailed answer! Good stuff